# How to configure redis.conf on openshift for redis

Tags: redis, openshift

Have a problem that by following the repo

https://github.com/razorinc/redis-openshift-example

When i start redis-server, it says "[12010] 25 Mar 20:14:53 # Opening port 6379: bind: Permission denied"

I tried to change port 0 to port 3128 but still get the same error....not sure why

--Update
When i tried to upgrade to redis 2.6 and uses --port parameter to bind to 3128, it still says
remote: [6844] 25 Mar 20:49:00.206 # Opening port 3128: bind: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Here's the OpenShift forum thread with suggested modifications:  https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-configure-redisconf-on-openshift-for-redis

Looks like calling redis-server uses default conf parameters that won't work well in the OpenShift gear environment so making the suggested changes to the redis.conf file and passing it into redis-server is the way to go.  There are suggestions for a pre-start and pre-stop hook as well.